# Tensorflow js error on Mac OS 11 with m1 chip

Tags: macos, tensorflow, apple-m1, tfjs-node

Trying to run basic get started example with tfjs in max m1 chip and getting illegal argument : 4 error. Is there anything specific need to be done for Mac m1 chip . Any help

Answer (score 0):

Compiled the libraries for Mac M1 chip. https://github.com/MeiyappanKannappa/libtensorflow-macos-m1

Comment: This there any other way? I can not access the file :/

Comment: Drive link needs permission ...